# Android Studio Project with multiple gradle files (one for each flavor)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on a project that has structure like

```
Project
  |+.gradle
  |+.idea
  |+.navigation
  |-app
     |+build
     |+keystore
     |+libs
     |-src
        |+androidTest
        |+Samsung
        |+Motorola
        |+HTC
     |-app.iml
     |-build.gradle
     |-build-Samsung.gradle
     |-build-Motorola.gradle
     |- ** How to add build-HTC.gradle file here? **
...
...
```

As you can see, there is specific code in Samsung and Motorola directories (not expaned above) and there are specific gradle files (build-Samsung.gradle and build-Motorola.gradle) in addition to build.gradle file.

I have to follow this structure and have to add another vendor specific flavor for say HTC.  How do I create "build-HTC.gradle" file in directory structure above in Android Studio.

Sorry, this might be very basic question but I was not able to find anything online and if I right-click on my src directory and chose New, I dont see option for gradle file.

Thanks

Comment: Just create a new file in this folder and call it buid-HTC,gradle

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti ach.. thanks :)  Much appreciated

Comment: @pixel how could you create build-Samsung.gradle and build-Motorola.gradle. And how android studio can merge 2 gradle files?